# Server not returning data in JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json

I am trying to make a simple API call using Node.js as the backend and React in the frontend. My Node.js file is not returning data in JSON, and I am not sure why. I need help on 2 things:

1. Why is my server not returning data in JSON?
2. In case it starts returning the above JSON is my API call good to work?

**Error msg:**

react-dom.development.js:14757 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
at throwOnInvalidObjectType (react-dom.development.js:14757:1)
**Code used on backend:**

```
const http = require("http");
let user={"name":"Leo"};
var server = http.createServer(function(req ,res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': JSON});
   
    res.json([{
        number: 1,
        name: 'CR7',
        gender: 'male'
      },
      {
        number: 2,
        name: 'LEO',
        gender: 'male'
      }
    ]);
    res.end(" done");
});
server.listen(8000);
```

**Code on the frontend(React):**

```
import "./index.css";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
      <form>
  <div>
  <div className="form-group">
    <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" className="form-control" />
    <small className="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div className="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" className="form-control"/>
  </div>
  <div className="form-group form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" />
    <label className="form-check-label" >Check me out</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" onClick="{fetcher()}"  className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
      </form>
      {//using state
      }
      function fetcher(){
        fetch("https://localhost:8000/user.name",{
          headers : { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
           }
    
        })
        .then((data)=>{return data.json()})
```

Comment: You are returning `Content-Type: [object JSON]` (because the `JSON` object is coerced to a string like that) instead of `Content-Type: application/json`. But, you also use `res.json`, which doesn't exist for an `http.ServerResponse` object! Are you confusing it with Express?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use http to call the local service http://localhost:8000/ . Test server  side i.e. node service call  in postman or curl request. ex. curl -I http://localhost:8000/ before integrating with React.

There is some error on your node script. res.json is available in express node module but not in http module.

See the updated code and sample output

```
const http = require("http");
let user={"name":"Leo"};
var server = http.createServer(function(req ,res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': JSON});
   
    //res.json();
    res.end(JSON.stringify([{
        number: 1,
        name: 'CR7',
        gender: 'male'
      },
      {
        number: 2,
        name: 'LEO',
        gender: 'male'
      }
    ]));
});
server.listen(8000)
```

Sample Output :

```
curl http://localhost:8000/

[{"number":1,"name":"CR7","gender":"male"},{"number":2,"name":"LEO","gender":"male"}]%
```

Comment: The content type is still incorrect

Comment: got it. getting required response from server. But API is still facing the error

Comment: I think the error facing now is CORS issue. i will install the middleware and use it. the issue I faced has been resolved. thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

`Content-Type` should be `application/json` in the server code.

Change `onClick="{fetcher()}"` to `onClick="{fetcher}"`, cause you want it to be called only when you click on the button, not immediately on render.
I also recommend moving the function above your `return`, for better organizing your code.
As `Senthil` mentioned above, you might also need to use `http` and not `https` in your API call.